# 20.04 - Can't persist IPTABLES rules

Tags: iptables

I need to share my wireless modem with another laptop via ethernet.  It works perfectly with:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -o wwan0 -s 192.168.9.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.9.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

But on reboot, they are gone.  I've looked at all different options, like:

1. sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v4 (says /etc/iptables doesn't exist)
2. iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 (doesn't seem to work)

And a few other options I tried from reading around.  So far I've had no success.  This seems like it should be a common problem with an easy fix, but I'm coming up blank.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `iptables-persistent` installed? What is the output of `systemctl status iptables`?